# How do I detect a text input's value and set a class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to make sure if a textbox has any content at all, that jQuery can show it's parent (an <li class="hidden_dedication">) element and set add a class of 'shown'. I'm pretty sure that it should be something like this, but cannot get it to work:

```
    if ($('li.hidden_dedication input').val() !== null) {
         $(this).parent().show().addClass('shown');
    }
```

I cannot figure it out.. any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare against the empty string `''` instead of `null`.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks for your response, I actually used this rather than macek's solution in the end.

Do you know how I would addClass to only the li's that have a value, not the ones that don't?

Comment: If you change `null` to `''`, your code looks fine, but that's assuming that `this` is actually referring to what you say it is. Without seeing more context I can't say for sure.